# Incorrect self join model example on guides.rubyonrails.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I feel the following self join model example given on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins is incorrect.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee",
    :foreign_key => "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee"
end
```

I feel it should be as following. Can you please suggest which one is correct and why?

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee",
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
end
```

My rationale: The model bearing `belongs_to` relation carries the foreign_key for the model it references to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is correct.

The "convention over configuration" mantra applies here, you only need to specify what the foreign key if it is not `"#{name_of_association}_id"`

Therefore `belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee"` implies the foreign key is `manager_id`

However `has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee"` assumes `subordinates_id` to be the childrens' foreign key, which is why if must be defined.  The definition of `:foreign_key` in a has_many will be for the child and will join against the current model's `id`.

Answer (score 0):

you're correct. That is how it should be.

However in that sort of situation i'd use acts_as_tree or similar, to build hierachy. allows you to call things such as `Employee.first.descendants` to find all who work for that person.